# Verify if this inequality is true

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $a_1, \; a_2, \cdots , \; a_n$ are positive real numbers with product $1$,

does this inequality hold, and if so how can one prove it?

$$(\sum a_i)^{7} \geq n^{5} \cdot (\sum a_i^2)^2$$

Thanks for any help.
P.S. Through trying cases I am pretty sure it does hold but don't know

how to deal with 1st powers being bigger than 2nd powers subject to constant and power etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote $A=\dfrac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n}{n}$, $S=\sqrt{\dfrac{a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots+a_n^2}{n}}$.

You need to prove that

$$
A^{7/4} \ge S.\tag{1}
$$

I have **doubts** in this inequality:

---

take $n=2$, $\quad$
$a_1=\dfrac{2}{3}, a_2=\dfrac{3}{2}$ $\quad$ ($a_1a_2=1$).

Then LHS of your inequality is 
$$
\left(\dfrac{2}{3}+\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^7 = \left(\dfrac{13}{6}\right)^7 \approx 224.153
$$
RHS of your inequality is 
$$
2^5 \cdot \left(\dfrac{4}{9}+\dfrac{9}{4}\right)^2 = 32\cdot \left(\dfrac{97}{36}\right)^2 \approx 232.321
$$

---

take $n=3$, $\quad$
$a_1=\dfrac{3}{4}, a_2=\dfrac{4}{5}, a_3=\dfrac{5}{3}$ $\quad$ ($a_1a_2a_3=1$).

Then LHS of your inequality is 
$$
\left(\dfrac{3}{4}+\dfrac{4}{5}+\dfrac{5}{3}\right)^7 = \left(\dfrac{193}{60}\right)^7 \approx 3563.218
$$
RHS of your inequality is 
$$
3^5 \cdot \left(\dfrac{9}{16}+\dfrac{16}{25}+\dfrac{25}{9}\right)^2 = 243\cdot \left(\dfrac{14329}{3600}\right)^2 = 3849.75451875
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_i = a_i^4$, then : $x_i > 0$, and $g(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = \displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$, and we need to prove: $\left(\dfrac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}\right)^7 \geq\left(\dfrac{x_1^2 + x_2^2 +...+x_n^2}{n}\right)^2 \iff 7\cdot Ln\left(\dfrac{x_1+x_2+..+x_n}{n}\right) - 2\cdot Ln\left(\dfrac{x_1^2 + x_2^2 +...+x_n^2}{n}\right) \geq 0 \ (*)$

Let $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = LHS$ of $(*)$. Then:

$\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ gives:

$\dfrac{7}{x_1+x_2+...+x_n} - \dfrac{4x_i}{x_1^2 + x_2^2 +...+x_n^2} = \lambda \displaystyle \prod_{k=1,k \neq i}^n x_k = \dfrac{\lambda}{x_i}$. Thus: $\forall i,j \in \{1,2,..,n\}$:

$\dfrac{7x_i}{x_1+x_2+...+x_n} - \dfrac{4x_i^2}{x_1^2 + x_2^2 +...+x_n^2} = \dfrac{7x_j}{x_1+x_2+...+x_n} - \dfrac{4x_j^2}{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + ...+ x_n^2} \iff \left(x_i - x_j\right)\left(\dfrac{7}{x_1+x_2+...+x_n} - \dfrac{4(x_i+x_j)}{x_1^2 + x_2^2 +...+x_n^2}\right) = 0$. From this a critical point of $f$ is $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = (1,1,1...,1)$, and $f_{min} = f(1,1,...,1) = 0$, proving the result.

P.S: I am aware that the LM method is not a favorite, and I am open to critic.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your solution, indeed a non Lagrange would be preferable, in case of one I won't accept your answer for a while.

Comment: As the other post shows, the critical point you have is **not** the minimum.

Comment: @Macavity: you are right. I regret not looking more carefully into it. Our solutions are not right, I thought your is right since you are very good at inequalities. I like your solution of the other post where you used Minskowski inequality. That was nice.